# abstract class multiple inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have following structure of classes:

- abstract class A
- class B extends class A
- abstract class C extends class B
- class D extends class C

I have a static method which has a return type **A** and returns **B** - this is ok.
I want to **change** this method, so it still has return type **A**, but it returns **D** - this causes problems:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    D cannot be resolved to a type
```

Why is this happening? They should have the same interface as the parent classes don't they?
**Edit:**

This is the method im trying to modify

```
public static CodeFormatter createDefaultCodeFormatter(Map<String, ?> options) {
        if (options == null)
            options = CCorePlugin.getOptions();
        return new CCodeFormatter(options);
    }
```

It is a class from the CDT Project (http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/commit/?id=a83be9db5b41c0a593425798a2af91060588b38a). Instead of CCodeFormatter I am trying to return MyFormatter. Class CCodeFormatter (*our B in example*) extends CodeFormatter (*our A in example*) and is extended by abstract class MyFormatter  (*or C in example*) and this class is extended by class MyFormatter (*D in example*). So I add its project to required bundles (in MANIFEST.MF) and then I import it and return new MyFormatter(options). In the end, this error happens.

```
public static CodeFormatter createDefaultCodeFormatter(Map<String, ?> options) {
        if (options == null)
            options = CCorePlugin.getOptions();
        return new MyFormatter(options);
    }
```

the "D" class

```
public class MyFormatter extends MyAbstractFormatter{

    @Override
    protected CodeFormatterVisitor getFormatterVisitor(DefaultCodeFormatterOptions preferences, int offset, int length) {
        return new MyFormatterVisitor(preferences, offset, length);
    }

}
```

and "C" class

```
public abstract class MyAbstractFormatter extends CCodeFormatter {

    public MyAbstractFormatter() {
        super();
    }

    public MyAbstractFormatter(DefaultCodeFormatterOptions preferences) {
        super(preferences);
    }

    public MyAbstractFormatter(DefaultCodeFormatterOptions defaultCodeFormatterOptions, Map<String, ?> options) {
        super(defaultCodeFormatterOptions, options);
    }

    public MyAbstractFormatter(Map<String, ?> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOptions(Map<String, ?> options) {
        super.setOptions(options);
    }

    @Override
    public TextEdit format(int kind, String source, int offset, int length, int indentationLevel, String lineSeparator) {
        return super.format(kind, source, offset, length, indentationLevel, lineSeparator);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you import `D`? (please show the code, otherwise it´s pretty unluckly you can get help if something else is wrong)

Comment: It has nothing to do with inheritance. All it says is that `D` is not visible at the point where you are trying to use it.

Comment: Of course I have imported D. Eclipse even offers me to change method type  `Type mismatch: cannot convert from D to A. +Change method return type to D`. Maybe there is a problem with bundle import in  Eclipse project, i will look into that.

Comment: You need to post some code, otherwise it's just guessing...

Comment: show your code, otherwise we can't provide the exact answer you need

Comment: Question have been edited. More code is not relevant. The code is too large, if something different is wrong, I will have to resolve it myself.

Comment: Paste code for your static method and class `D` please

Comment: It can be relevant! The problem may be in D (MyFormatter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problems seems to be in cyclic dependency (and not in abstract classes). My project is dependent on CDT project and I am trying to add my project to this project's required bundles, I am making this CDT project dependent on my project. (Altought Eclipse usually detects this problem, this is probably not the case).